# Exercicio sobre peso ideal (Linguagem C)

Tags: c

Alguem saberia me explicar como eu poderia fazer parte da "situacao" nesse exercicio? como eu faria pra representar isso no algoritmo? so falta isso pra concluir, o resto funciona..
[image: Exercicio]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char sexo, sair;
float peso, altura, diferenca, pi, situacao1, situacao2;

main()

{
    do{
        printf("Digite o seu sexo, M para masculino ou F para feminino: ");
        scanf(" %c", &sexo);


        printf("Digite a sua altura(METROS): ");
        scanf("%f", &altura);


        printf("Digite o seu peso(KG): ");
        scanf("%f", &peso);

        if(sexo == 'M'){
            pi = (72.7*altura)-58;
            diferenca = peso - pi;
            printf("O seu peso ideal e: %0.2f\n", pi);
            printf("Diferenca de peso: %0.2f\n", diferenca);

        }else if(sexo == 'F'){
            pi = (62.1*altura)-44.7;
            diferenca = peso - pi;
            printf("O seu peso ideal e: %0.2f\n", pi);
            printf("Diferenca de peso: %0.2f\n", diferenca);

        }                                 

        situacao1 = (pi*0.05)+pi;  //eu pensei em fazer isso e dps adicionar IF
        situacao2 = pi-(pi*0.05);  //mas nao deu certo..


        printf("Sair [S/N]:");
        scanf(" %c", &sair);
        system("cls");
        if((sair == 'S')||(sair == 's')) break;

    }while(1);


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que exatamente não deu certo?  Você está calculando os thresholds para gordo em `situacao1` e magro em `situacao2`. Você tem o peso atual dele dele na variável `peso` então só faltam as comparações... E.g., `if (peso >= situacao1)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta testar direto e imprimir a mensagem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char sexo, sair;
float peso, altura, diferenca, pi, situacao1, situacao2;

main()

{
    do{
        printf("Digite o seu sexo, M para masculino ou F para feminino: ");
        scanf(" %c", &sexo);


        printf("Digite a sua altura(METROS): ");
        scanf(" %f", &altura);


        printf("Digite o seu peso(KG): ");
        scanf(" %f", &peso);

        if(sexo == 'M'){
            pi = (72.7*altura)-58;
            diferenca = peso - pi;
            printf("O seu peso ideal e: %0.2f\n", pi);
            printf("Diferenca de peso: %0.2f\n", diferenca);

        }else if(sexo == 'F'){
            pi = (62.1*altura)-44.7;
            diferenca = peso - pi;
            printf("O seu peso ideal e: %0.2f\n", pi);
            printf("Diferenca de peso: %0.2f\n", diferenca);

        }                                

        if (peso > pi * 1.05)
            printf("Gordo\n");
        else
            if (peso < pi * 0.95)
                printf("Magro\n");
            else
                printf("Ideal\n");

        printf("Sair [S/N]:");
        scanf(" %c", &sair);
        system("cls");
        if((sair == 'S')||(sair == 's')) break;

    }while(1);


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: pq você colocou ali no if 1.05 e no outro 0.95? pq seria esses números?

Comment: Matematicamente: `pi * 1.05` é o mesmo que `pi + pi*0.05`, isto é: pi * ( 1 + 0.05),  e `pi * 0.95` é o mesmo que `pi - pi*0.05`, isto é: pi * (1 - 0.05), ou seja pi + 5% e pi - 5%.

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário